# Puppet VCSRepo SVN checkout only once or if repository updates

Tags: svn, repository, puppet

So i have a module in which I use vcsrepo to checkout repository. But the problem is every time puppet runs it checkout the repository and it takes too long to finish which is annoying plus it eats up resources on the machine.

```
vcsrepo { "/data/www/local_testing/src":
    ensure => present,
    provider => svn,
    owner => 'www-data',
    group => 'www-data',
    source => "svn+ssh://myuser@svnrepourl.com"
  }
```

So is there a way or condition which I can put so that i can stop it from getting the repo every single time puppet runs or it should only get the files which changed once the repo is setup.

It will also be fine if it just gets the repo first time puppet runs, after that user can do svn up to keep the repo updated.

Comment: The `vcsrepo` type should detect that the checkout exists already. There is some issue with your setup. Please run `puppet agent --test -dv` and observe the debug output for clues as to why the current state is not detected correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you (well, "we" since I just ran into this myself) are using an old version.  It looks like this issue is about two years old: https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/16954

Amazing if it's still around, considering the popularity of git and the fact that it's the only VCS provider officially supported by puppet.